# finding center of circle

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, circles

How can I calculate center of a circle $x,y$? I have 2 points on the circumference of the circle and the angle between them.

The 2 points on the circle are $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2)$. The angle between them is $\theta$. I know all these values; how can I calculate the center from these values?

Comment: what do you mean by the angle between the points?

Comment: I guess he means the angle inscribed at centre by the line joining the two points.

Comment: @NikhilBellarykar. Ahh ok. I see. He should have been more explicit.

Comment: Note that all the answers give two solutions.  This is correct-the center can be either side of the bisector line.

Answer (score 3):

You could:

First, find the distance between, and the midpoint of, the two points.

Then draw the right triangle formed one of the given points, $p_1$, the midpoint, $m$, and the center, $c$, of the circle (this will be a right triangle since a perpendicular bisector  of a chord on a circle passes through the center of the circle).

You know the length of the side $\overline{p_1m}$ of this triangle, since you know the distance between the given two points. You also know that the angle $\angle mcp_1$ is half the given angle.

Now, a bit of trig will allow you to find the side length $\overline{cm}$ of the triangle. Let's call that length $l$.

Next, find the equation of the line containing $\overline{cm}$ (it's slope will be the negative reciprocal of the slope of the line segment joining the two given points).

Let's say that equation is $y=m_0x+b$.

If $(c_1,c_2)$ are the coordinates of the center and $(m_1,m_2)$ are the coordinates of the midpoint, you'd know:
$$
l = \sqrt{(c_1-m_1  )^2+(c_2-m_2)^2 }
$$
and 
$$
c_2=m_0 c_1+b.
$$
Finally, you'd solve the above equations for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

(There are probably slicker ways to do this.)

---

[image]

As Ross Millikan points out, there are two solutions (hence, there is another somewhat different diagram for the solution not represented by the above diagram)...

Comment: what is b and m0 in second equation?

Comment: @coure2011 The equation of the line $cm$ is $y= m_0 x+b$. $m_0$ is the slope of the line and $b$ is the $y$-intercept.  $m_0$ is the negative reciprocal of the line segment $p_1p_2$. You can find the value of $b$ by substituting the values of the point $m$ into the equation.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy using complex numbers. 
You can represent every point $(x,y)$ through the complex number $x+iy$ and vice versa. It's just easier to calculate with them this way.

Let $P_1 = 0$, then we get $S = \frac {P_2} 2$ as the starting point on the bisector. Multiply by $i$ to rotate by 90°, thus we need to go in the direction of $i\frac{S}{|S|}$. The distance is $d = \frac{|S|}{\tan \frac \theta 2}$, thus we get the center by

$$M = S + i\frac{S}{|S|}\cdot d = S(1 + \frac i {\tan \frac \theta 2})$$

Now for arbitrary points $P_1, P_2$, we get
$$ M = \frac 1 2 (P_2-P_1) (1 + \frac i {\tan \frac \theta 2}) + P_1. $$

Comment: What is itan? and M?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Find the perpendicular bisector of $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: I dont think this is enough.

Comment: Let $\theta$ be the angle between them. Then, starting from  each point, make an angle of $(90-\theta)$ between the bisector. The point where the angle rays intersect the bisector is the centre.

Answer (score 0):

Angle at centre is twice the angle between the given points

let centre be (x,y)

form equations for line segments joining centre to these 2 points respectively

you also have the ansgle between them, so solve to get (x,y)

Comment: can you please explain it more?

Answer (score 0):

The bisector of the line segment $\overline{P_1P_2}$ passes through the circle's center.
Let $\alpha = \frac \theta 2$ and you get the distance $d$ to travel on the bisector by $$\tan \alpha = \frac{\overline{P_1P_2}}{d}.$$

Comment: Should the numerator of the fraction be $\frac{1}{2}P_1P_2$, since the right triangle with $\alpha$ and $d$ is formed with the midpoint of $\overline{P_1P_2}$?

Comment: what this? how to find Cx and Cy center of circle?